# Exchange POP3 has stopped allowing emails sent via GRAPH to be downloaded

Tags: email, graph, outlook, exchange-server, pop3

In short, the Exchange (office 365) POP server is not allowing me to download messages that have been sent using the GRAPH api.

In full; we have a service that sends an email to an external service, and then looks for a response. This service currently uses smtp to send, and pop3 to receive the response, connecting to smtp.office365.com and outlook.office365.com respectively.
This was working fine until around 7am BST 02/07/2020, and now the POP3 is returning the error "-ERR Message corrupted".
I have logged into the account using outlook web and deleted the emails that were in there, but when the service sends a new email, and the response is sent, it reports the same error.
If I add the account to outlook as a pop3 mailbox, it also cant download the emails.
If however I send an email from another exchange mailbox using outlook, our service, and outlook is able to download it.
The remote service that is sending the response emails that we cant download using pop anymore is using the GRAPH api to send to the email.
So it seems that it is only emails sent using the GRAPH api that it is not allowing us to download.

I've raised this with Office 365 support, and they claim they don't support POP3, and it must be a development issue. I'm not convinced, but has anyone else had the same issue / have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: After further investigation, this only seems to be an issue if setting the replyTo address. If I don't set the replyTo address, then the mail item comes through correctly

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that this is nothing to do with sending with GRAPH, but is to do with if you have set the replyTo option. This can be replicated by sending from Outlook, and using the "Direct Replies To" option. MS have now reproduced it, and are looking further into it.